# Java - Overriding method which has generic type parameter and type casting it while invoking it

Tags: java, oop, overriding, generic-type-argument

I have a utility class `OldRemote` which has been deprecated now, but still it will be used for a while till the new class `NewRemote` is stable. And both the utility classes has the same method names and parameters, But the return type pojo classes are different. Even return type pojo structure is same, but naming is different.

In simple, both the function return types are pojo's with different field names.

Is there any generic way to handle this below usecase ?

I have created a service interface which has the generic method contract of both old and new class.

```
public interface RemoteService {

    //contract [ return type is object to receive all/any Pojo classes ]
    Object turnOnTV();

    static Service GetRemoteservice(boolean isOldRemote){
        if(isOldRemote){
            return new OldRemote();
        }
        return new NewRemote();
    }
}
```

OldRemote Class

```
public class OldRemote implements RemoteService{
    @Override
    public OldPojo turnOnTV() {
        OldPojo oldPojo = new OldPojo();
        System.out.println("OldPojo");
        return oldPojo;
    }
}
```

NewRemote Class

```
public class NewRemote implements Service{
    @Override
    public NewPojo turnOnTV() {
        NewPojo newPojo = new NewPojo();
        System.out.println("NewPojo");
        return newPojo;
    }
}
```

Demo usage of above implementation.

```
public class DemoTvRemote {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        RemoteService remoteService1 = RemoteService.GetRemoteservice(true);
        OldPojo oldRemote = (OldPojo) remoteService1.turnOnTV();

        RemoteService remoteService2 = RemoteService.GetRemoteservice(false);
        NewPojo shr = (NewPojo) Service2.test();
    }
}
```

This above code works fine. But the problem is I don't want to type cast in all the places where `turnOnTV()` is used in my entire code base. Even If I have to do that, I will have to write a condition to switch between `OldPojo` and `NewPojo` where ever the `turnOnTV()` is invoked.

Is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base class or interface they both extend/implement.

```
public abstract class RemoteServiceBase<E> {
    public abstract E turnOnTv();
}

public class NewRemoteService extends RemoteServiceBase<NewRemotePojo >{
    public NewRemotePojo turnOnTv() {
         return new NewRemotePojo();
    } 
}


public class OldRemoteService extends RemoteServiceBase<OldRemotePojo >{
    public OldRemotePojo turnOnTv() {
         return new OldRemotePojo();
    } 
}
```

This would still only work if you know the service type. Otherwise you work with the common generic type as one would expect.

Comment: No need for `RemoteServiceBase`.  An interface can be generic:  `public interface RemoteService<E>`

Comment: Ah, so you did;  I missed that.  Why go out of your way to deviate from the code in the question, then?

Answer (score 0):

We can deal with this with the following approach :

1) We can create a dummy POJO class in a common location with having the reference of both OldPojo and NewPojo as data members

```
public class CommonPojo  {

     OldPojo oldPojo;
     NewPojo newPojo; 

     public void setOldPojo(OldPojo oldPojo){
         this.oldPojo=oldPojo;
      }

      public void setNewPojo(NewPojo newPojo){
         this.newPojo=newPojo;
      }

     public OldPojo getOldPojo(){
         return oldPojo;
      }

      public NewPojo getNewPojo(){
         return newPojo;
      }
    }
```

2)We can  write a Utility method as follow which can give an object of commonpojo :

```
public class CommonRemote {


 public  static CommonPojo turnOnTv(Boolean isOldRemote){

    CommonPojo commonPojo = new CommonPojo  

    if(isOldRemote){
         OldPojo oldPojo =new OldPojo();
         commonPojo.setOldPojo(oldPojo);

       }else{
           NewPojo newPojo =new NewPojo();
           commonPojo.setNewPojo (newPojo);
       }

    }

}
```

3) Use this method as turnOnTv() as Follows :

```
public class DemoTvRemote {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

       CommonPojo remote1 = CommonRemote.turnOnTv(true);
        OldPojo oldRemote = remote1.getOldPojo();

       CommonPojo remote2 = CommonRemote.turnOnTv(false);
        NewPojo newRemote = remote2.getNewPojo();

    }
}
```

with this approach with little changes in code We can achieve your requirement without any typecasting.

Comment: @Carl is it what you are looking for ?